# Resorting bits of ulong in a specific order

Tags: c#, sorting, bit-manipulation

For a computer game I work with a bitmask (I hope I use this term correctly) which is stored in a **ulong**.
The bitmask is interacting with other bitmasks which turns 1s of the bits to 0s when the other bitmask is overlapping. When the interaction with other bitmasks is over, I want to check if specific bits are 1, one by one. However, in a specific order that is not following the order in the ulong.

They are originally sorted differently because of symmetry reasons during the interaction phase which makes rotation of the pre-sorted bitmask possible.

I wrote down the order of the original bits. If that order is needed to help me, here it is:

```
31, 39, 34, 27, 43, 30, 38, 26, 42, 33, 29, 37, 23, 47, 25, 41, 22, 46, 32, 28, 36, 21, 45, 24, 40, 20, 44, 48, 16, 49, 17, 50, 18, 51, 19, 12, 52, 8, 56, 13, 53, 4, 60, 0, 14, 54, 9, 57, 15, 55, 5, 61, 1, 10, 58, 6, 62, 11, 59, 2, 7, 63, 3
```

(for example, the first number is 31. That means that the 31th (counting from 0) bit of the pre-sorted ulong has to go into the first bit of the sorted ulong. Then the value of the 39th bit goes into the second of the sorted ulong and so on)

This part of my game code is the most performance critical so I look for the most efficient way to do this. It is related to crowd mechanics and the more efficient this code will turn out, the more crowd member I can and will include.

I am also willing to use lookup tables of a low MB size. An idea of mine regarding this is to split the ulong into four shorts, put them into a lookuptable each which returns a sorted short. But as many bits need to be moved between and not only within these four chunks, this alone won't work.

Another idea I have is this:

```
ulong unsorted = x;
ulong sorted = 0;
sorted += (unsorted & 0x0001000010000000) >> 18 //bits that are shifted the same manner
//go on
```

Comment: You could store `bitmask % 2` in an array and set `bitmask = bitmask / 2` in a loop and then access the array with your indexes (reverted if needed as you stored the last bit in the first position of the array)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way to do this permutation is:

```
ulong permute(ulong x)
{
    x = bit_permute_step(x, 0x00000000c539d22d, 32);
    x = bit_permute_step(x, 0x0000cbc10000749e, 16);
    x = bit_permute_step(x, 0x0039007e00a9007f, 8);
    x = bit_permute_step(x, 0x06010e04070e0507, 4);
    x = bit_permute_step(x, 0x2113320311022110, 2);
    x = bit_permute_step(x, 0x5401151151100141, 1);
    x = bit_permute_step(x, 0x0032323110011333, 2);
    x = bit_permute_step(x, 0x030b0a0b080e0d00, 4);
    x = bit_permute_step(x, 0x00a5009500220097, 8);
    x = bit_permute_step(x, 0x00005cd6000043cc, 16);
    x = bit_permute_step(x, 0x00000000b3f003f3, 32);
    return x;
}
```

Where `bit_permute_step` is defined as:

```
ulong bit_permute_step(ulong source, ulong mask, int shift)
{
    ulong t = ((source >> shift) ^ source) & mask;
    return (source ^ t) ^ (t << shift);
}
```

That construction is a full Beneš network of 11 steps (6 * 2 - 1, where 6 is the base 2 logarithm of 64). That's a very general technique that can handle any permutation, in many cases there are special-case techniques that are better, but I could not find one for this.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of preliminary notes:

- Your example data has only 63 values. For the purpose of my code examples below, I've arbitrarily adding the missing value of `35` to the end of the list.
- There isn't any detail in your question about how you got into this bit-shuffled situation in the first place. It should go without saying, but I'll mention anyway: the *best* solution is the one that removes the problem altogether. Whether this is possible in your exact scenario, never mind how that might be done, I can't say because the details are missing from the question.

All that said…

> Another idea I have is this:
>
> ```cs
> ulong unsorted = x;
> ulong sorted = 0;
> sorted += (unsorted & 0x0001000010000000) >> 18 //bits that are shifted the same manner
> //go on
> ```

That idea might work fine. But you haven't provided enough detail in your question for anyone else to know, because we don't have any information about why the bits are being reordered the way they are. You seem to have in mind writing special-case code to take advantage of whatever pattern it is that led to the bit ordering in the first place, but without specific details about that pattern, no one else can flesh out the idea.

> An idea of mine regarding this is to split the ulong into four shorts, put them into a lookuptable each which returns a sorted short. But as many bits need to be moved between and not only within these four chunks, this alone won't work.

That idea will work too. You're right that you can't map to `short` values (or even `ushort`). But you can map to `ulong` values, and then combine the results.

Of course, the first and most important thing for any code is for it to *work*. So IMHO it would make sense to start with a simpler implementation that can be verified. With that done, then you can move on to alternatives.

Here is one option:

```cs
static readonly int[] bitOrder = // NOTE: 35 not in original example, added here at end arbitrarily
{                                // so that a valid implementation can be demonstrated
    31, 39, 34, 27, 43, 30, 38, 26, 42, 33, 29, 37, 23, 47, 25, 41,
    22, 46, 32, 28, 36, 21, 45, 24, 40, 20, 44, 48, 16, 49, 17, 50,
    18, 51, 19, 12, 52,  8, 56, 13, 53,  4, 60,  0, 14, 54,  9, 57,
    15, 55,  5, 61,  1, 10, 58,  6, 62, 11, 59,  2,  7, 63,  3, 35
};

private static ulong[] BuildBitwiseMapping()
{
    ulong[] bitwiseMapping = new ulong[bitOrder.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < bitwiseMapping.Length; i++)
    {
        bitwiseMapping[i] = 1UL << bitOrder[i];
    }

    return bitwiseMapping;
}

private static ulong SortBits(ulong[] bitwiseMapping, ulong value)
{
    ulong sorted = 0, mask = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < bitwiseMapping.Length; i++, mask <<= 1)
    {
        if ((value & bitwiseMapping[i]) != 0)
        {
            sorted |= mask;
        }
    }

    return sorted;
}
```

You would call `BuildBitwiseMapping()` first, and then use the returned array for every call to `SortBits()`. Naturally, you could just incorporate the built array as a `static readonly` field, to simplify the call to `SortBits()`.

This has to loop once for each bit, which is not necessarily the most efficient. But other than the loop condition, it's strictly just lookup and bitwise OR operations, and so could be reasonably fast already.

If you want to improve on that using your lookup-table idea, that's simple:

```cs
private static ulong[][] BuildWordwiseMapping(ulong[] bitwiseMapping)
{
    ulong[][] result = new ulong[4][];
    ulong increment = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = new ulong[ushort.MaxValue + 1];
        ulong value = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j <= ushort.MaxValue; j++)
        {
            result[i][j] = SortBits(bitwiseMapping, value);
            value += increment;
        }

        increment = value;
    }

    return result;
}

private static ulong SortBits(ulong[][] wordwiseMapping, ulong value)
{
    ulong sorted = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < wordwiseMapping.Length; i++, value >>= 16)
    {
        int ushortPart = (int)(value & 0xffff);

        sorted |= wordwiseMapping[i][ushortPart];
    }

    return sorted;
}
```

The above starts with the 64-element bit-wise table from the first example, and uses that to build four larger tables that can be used for a word-wise lookup.

You need four different tables, one for each subset of bits from the original `ulong` value, because of course they each map differently. They can be spread out across the entire `ulong` result, so the table element size still needs to be `ulong`.

This gives you four tables, each with 65536 elements, each element being 8 bytes long, for a total memory footprint of 2MB. On the other hand, while the simpler bit-wise version requires 64 loop iterations for each value, the word-wise version requires only 4. This could improve your throughput considerably. Or it might have little effect overall; it really depends on just how much of a bottleneck this code really would be anyway, and on how much faster the four-table version would be.

You might notice in the above that technically, the value `0` doesn't actually need to be handled in each table, because there won't be any bits set for such values, regardless of where they show up in the original `ulong`. But it's likely that it would cost more performance-wise to actually *compare* against `0` and handle that special case, then to just lookup the NOP "zero maps to zero" value.